# Make a new list of rules by matching up keys from two given lists of rules

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, rule

Consider two lists of rules:

```
list1 = {"a" -> "apple", "b" -> "banana", "c" -> "cucumber"};
list2 = {"A" -> "pie", "B" -> "split", "C" -> "salad"};
```

I'm looking to come up with a way to "combine" these lists into a third list of rules `Rule[key, val]` in which `key` is a value from a rule taken from `list1` and `val` is the value taken from the matching rule in `list2`. "Matching" here is subject to a custom criterion.

In this example, I want to get the list

```
{"apple" -> "pie", "banana" -> "split", "cucumber" -> "salad"}
```

where the combining criterion is that the keys consist of the same letter; that is, `"a"` and `"A"` satisfy some version of `StringMatchQ[#1, #2, IgnoreCase -> True] &`, for instance.

Is there a good way to do this?

For this particular example, this works (though I bet there's a neater way to do it):

```
With[
    {list1 = {"a" -> "apple", "b" -> "banana", "c" -> "cucumber"},
     list2 = {"A" -> "pie", "B" -> "split", "C" -> "salad"}},
    (Reverse /@ list1) /. (list2 /. s_String :> ToLowerCase[s])
]
(* {"apple" -> "pie", "banana" -> "split", "cucumber" -> "salad"} *)
```

But in my more general use case, I'll have `list1` and `list2` with keys like `{"x1", "y1", "z1"}` and `{"X-one", "Y-one", "Z-one"}`, with the matching criterion that values to-be-`Rule`-ified are the ones whose corresponding keys contain `1` and `one`.

P.S. Sorry if the title is confusing, I wasn't quite sure how to word it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1 /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[b, ToUpperCase[a] /. list2]
```

> {"apple" -> "pie", "banana" -> "split", "cucumber" -> "salad"}

or

```
list2 /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[ToLowerCase[a] /. list1, b]
```

> {"apple" -> "pie", "banana" -> "split", "cucumber" -> "salad"}

Also:

```
Values @ GroupBy[Join[list1, list2], ToLowerCase[#[[1]]] &,  Apply[Rule]@*Values]
```

> {"apple" -> "pie", "banana" -> "split", "cucumber" -> "salad"}

and

```
Values @ Merge[Apply[Rule]][MapAt[ToLowerCase, #, {All, 1}] & /@ {list1, list2}]
```

> {"apple" -> "pie", "banana" -> "split", "cucumber" -> "salad"}

For general cases like the second example in OP, you can define case-specific conversion rules and convert keys of one of the input lists before using `Merge` or `GroupBy`:

```
k2Tok1 = StringReplace[a__ ~~ "-" ~~ b__ :> 
  ToLowerCase[a] <> ToString[Interpreter["SemanticNumber"][b]]] ;

k1Tok2 = StringReplace[ a__ ~~ i : NumberString :>
   ToUpperCase[a] <> "-" <> IntegerName[FromDigits@i]] ;
```

***Examples:***

```
k1 = {"x1", "y1", "z5"};
k2 = {"X-one", "Y-one", "Z-six"};

k1Tok2 @ k1
```

> {"X-one", "Y-one", "Z-five"}

```
k2Tok1 @ k2
```

> {"x1", "y1", "z6"}

```
lst1 = {"x1" -> "apple", "y1" -> "banana", "z6" -> "cucumber"};
lst2 = {"X-one" -> "pie", "Y-one" -> "split", "Z-six" -> "salad"};

lst1 /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[b, k1Tok2[a] /. lst2]
```

> {"apple" -> "pie", "banana" -> "split", "cucumber" -> "salad"}

```
lst2 /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[k2Tok1[a] /. lst1, b]
```

> {"apple" -> "pie", "banana" -> "split", "cucumber" -> "salad"}